# How to populate a Bootstrap table using selected elements of an array of objects using pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to to populate a Bootstrap table from an array of objects using pure JavaScript.

Here is my `data.js` file:

**JavaScript**

```
let testData = [

    {
        id : 1,
        firstName : 'John',
        lastName : 'Smith',
        age :  35,
        retired : false
    },

    {
        id : 2,
        firstName : 'Mary',
        lastName : 'Williams',
        age :  27,
        retired : false
    },

    {   
        id : 3,
        firstName : 'Bill',
        lastName : 'Jones',
        age :  83,
        retired : true
    },

    {
        id : 4,
        firstName : 'Sally',
        lastName : 'Lee',
        age :  49,
        retired : false
    }
]
```

In my `main.js` file, I have the following function that builds the HTML and populates the table with ***only*** the `firstName`, `lastName`, and `age`.  **But, this function is not working.**

```
function createTable(data) {
    var tr;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].firstName + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].lastName + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].age + "</td>");     
    }end(tr);
    }

createTable(testData)
```

Here is my `index.html` file:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
     <div id="content-1"></div>

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">First Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Age</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>    

    <tbody>
        <!-- what goes here? -->

    </tbody>


    <script src="./js/data.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any assistance would be most appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: *is not working* is too little information to be able to help you. What errors are you encountering? What do you mean with *pure JavaScript*?

Comment: You had me in the first half when you mentioned "pure  javascript" until I noticed the usage of jquery...

Answer (score 0):

1. `tbody` should be inside `table` element.
2. You created the `tr` element correctly, but you didn't `append` it to the `tbody`.

```js
const testData = [

    {
        id : 1,
        firstName : 'John',
        lastName : 'Smith',
        age :  35,
        retired : false
    },

    {
        id : 2,
        firstName : 'Mary',
        lastName : 'Williams',
        age :  27,
        retired : false
    },

    {   
        id : 3,
        firstName : 'Bill',
        lastName : 'Jones',
        age :  83,
        retired : true
    },

    {
        id : 4,
        firstName : 'Sally',
        lastName : 'Lee',
        age :  49,
        retired : false
    }
]

function createTable(data) {
    
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].firstName + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].lastName + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].age + "</td>");
        $('tbody').append(tr)
    }
}

createTable(testData)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
     <div id="content-1"></div>

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">First Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Age</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <!-- what goes here? -->

        </tbody>
    </table>    

</body>
</html>
```

**With pure javascript ( without jquery )**

```js
const testData = [

    {
        id : 1,
        firstName : 'John',
        lastName : 'Smith',
        age :  35,
        retired : false
    },

    {
        id : 2,
        firstName : 'Mary',
        lastName : 'Williams',
        age :  27,
        retired : false
    },

    {   
        id : 3,
        firstName : 'Bill',
        lastName : 'Jones',
        age :  83,
        retired : true
    },

    {
        id : 4,
        firstName : 'Sally',
        lastName : 'Lee',
        age :  49,
        retired : false
    }
]

const tableBody = document.querySelector('tbody');

function createTable(data) {
    
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.innerHTML = `<td>${data[i].firstName}</td>
        <td>${data[i].lastName}</td>
        <td>${data[i].age}</td>`
        tableBody.append(tr)
    }
}

createTable(testData)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
   

</head>
<body>
     <div id="content-1"></div>

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">First Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Age</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <!-- what goes here? -->

        </tbody>
    </table>    

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added a fiddle link with the requested output. If my understanding isn't wrong, you have data in .js file as an array of objects and you need to populate the data in bootstrap table. Hopefully it helps!

**HTML**

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.0/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.0/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="id">Id</th>
      <th data-field="firstName">First Name</th>
      <th data-field="lastName">Last Name</th>
      <th data-field="age">Age</th>
      <th data-field="retired">Retired</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
var $table = $("#table");
    
    $(function () {
      let testData = [
        {
          id: 1,
          firstName: "John",
          lastName: "Smith",
          age: 35,
          retired: false,
        },
    
        {
          id: 2,
          firstName: "Mary",
          lastName: "Williams",
          age: 27,
          retired: false,
        },
    
        {
          id: 3,
          firstName: "Bill",
          lastName: "Jones",
          age: 83,
          retired: true,
        },
    
        {
          id: 4,
          firstName: "Sally",
          lastName: "Lee",
          age: 49,
          retired: false,
        },
      ];
      var data = [];
    
      testData.forEach(function (value) {
        data.push(value);
      });
      $table.bootstrapTable({ data: data });
    });
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uvbqt6gc/

Answer (score 0):

`<tbody>` must always be located before `<tfoot>` or as the last child of a `<table>`. If a `<tbody>` is not added in HTML, it is added to each `<table>` by the browser by default.

**Details are commented in example**

```js
const data = [{
  id: 1,
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Smith',
  age: 35,
  retired: false
}, {
  id: 2,
  firstName: 'Mary',
  lastName: 'Williams',
  age: 27,
  retired: false
}, {
  id: 3,
  firstName: 'Bill',
  lastName: 'Jones',
  age: 83,
  retired: true
}, {
  id: 4,
  firstName: 'Sally',
  lastName: 'Lee',
  age: 49,
  retired: false
}];

// Reference <tbody>
const tB = document.querySelector("table").tBodies[0];

/**
 * @desc - Generates table rows from data. A <table> must be in DOM.
 * @param {object<DOM>}   tbody   - Reference to a <table> or <tbody>
 * @param {array<object>} array   - An array of objects
 * @param {number<rest>}  headers - One or more numbers representing the
 *        index numbers of the first object of the array's keys. If 
 *        undefined it @default to all of the keys.
 */
function createRows(tbody, array, ...headers) {
  /**
   * Make an array of keys from the first object
   * ["id", "firstName", "lastName", "age", "retired"]
   */
  const keys = Object.keys(array[0]); 
  let hdrs;
  /**
    * If >...headers< is undefined, then >hdrs< is keys unfiltered
    * Otherwise >hdrs< is filtered by the index numbers of >...headers<
    * [...headers] = [1, 2, 3] 
    * hdrs = ["firstName", "lastName", "age"]
    */
  if ([...headers].length < 1) {
    hdrs = keys;
  } else {
    hdrs = keys.filter((_, i) => [...headers].includes(i));
  }
  /**
   * Add a <tr> for each object in the array
   * Add a <td> for each key of >hdrs<
   * Add the value that corresponds to each key of >hdrs< to each <td>
   */
  array.forEach(obj => {
    let tr = tbody.insertRow();
    hdrs.forEach(key => tr.insertCell().textContent = obj[key]);
  });
}

createRows(tB, data, 1, 2, 3);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <main class="container">
    <section class="row">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">First Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Age</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
      </table>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```